# Reactjs remove specific index of array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-modal

I have a modal that is used to fill in a form. When clicking submit, the modal will close and update the array.

When I want to delete the specific array, what happens under the array is also deleted.

[Here is the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-solomon-p83u2?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using prevState to filter in setState

```
  let actionRemoveDocs = (cell, event) => {
event.preventDefault();
// console.log(inputArrDocuments.filter(docs => docs.documentUuid !== cell))
setTimeout(() => {
  setInputArrDocuments(prev =>
    prev.filter(docs => docs.documentArray !== cell)
  );
}, 500);};
```